# tf2::toMsg(tf2::Vector3) in ROS2 Foxy?

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on ROS2 Foxy and cannot find the toMsg() function for Vector3 that used to be in tf2_geometry_msgs.h. In previous versions the following function exists:

geometry_msgs::Vector3 tf2::toMsg (const tf2::Vector3 &in)

Has it been moved or removed completely? What shall I use instead? I do not really fancy to use the stamped version of Vector3.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367561/tf2::tomsg(tf2::vector3)-in-ros2-foxy?/) by [rblilja](https://answers.ros.org/users/65288/rblilja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rblilja](https://answers.ros.org/users/65288/rblilja/) on 2020-12-12**:
I have a custom message with multiple vectors and a header (with time and frame id). Therefore I don't see the necessity to use stamped vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's `Vector3Stamped` now. Most all of the ROS2 TF2 non-`Stamped` conversions were removed. I don't know the exact reason why, but I'm going to speculate that it has to do with TF2 in general really only supporting `Stamped` types so the conversions to/from messages really don't need the non-stamped versions anymore. The only exception I can find to that is `Quaternion` which is needed by the other functions regarding the `transform` message.

https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/ros2/tf2_geometry_msgs/include/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h#L110.

Just as a policy, if you're using TF2, it's good to use stamped variants so you don't make silly mistakes like misassigning frames/data to their proper timestamps and frames.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1